# foreach-loop with for-loop inside does not display errors

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, domdocument

I'm trying to get certain values from multiple XMLDocuments.
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I'm new to PHP syntax and it doesn't output any errors. The first part where I "get elements from channel" and "output elements from channel" works fine, but the for-loop to output the items does not work.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$xmlDoc0 = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc0->load("http://www.heute.at/storage/rss/rss/heute.xml");
$xmlDoc1 = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc1->load("http://kurier.at/newsfeed/oesterreich_rss.xml");

$xmlDocArray = array(
            0 => $xmlDoc0,
            1 => $xmlDoc1
            );

foreach ($xmlDocArray as $key => $value){

//get elements from "<channel>"
$channel=$value->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
$channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_link = $channel->getElementsByTagName('link')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('description')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

//output elements from "<channel>"
echo("<p><a href='" . $channel_link
  . "'>" . $channel_title . "</a>");
echo("<br>");
echo($channel_desc . "</p>"); 

//get "<item>" elements
$x=$value->getElementsByTagName('item');
for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {
  $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_img=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')
  ->item(0)->getAttribute('url');

  //output "<item>" elements
  echo ("<a href='" . $item_link
  . "'>" . $item_title . "</a>");

}
}
```

Comment: I see ur code works.

Comment: what error you facing ??

Comment: I get a blank page when I execute this script :(